# Partitions in Mac

Tags: macos, partition

Recently I got a Mac mini with OS X 10.7 installed. Right now it has one 500GB hard disk.

What I want to know is wheather we can partition the hard disk like on Windows. I would like to save my working files in a separate partition so that if I need to re-install (clean install) the operating system on the Mac, my working files stay intact.

Comment: No need to capitalize Mac: is not an acronym

Comment: You can reinstall the Mac OS without having the need to restore your installed applications and home folder. If you're new to Mac, you should really check out [Time Machine](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/#timemachinebasics) for backups.

Comment: Really good advice ^ don't bother going through the hassle of 2 partitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disks can be partitioned without any problem: just open Disk Utility, select the disk and choose "Partition" on the right.

You will be able to resize your partition and create an additional one.

[image]

Comment: You can't use Disk Utility to non-destructively partition/resize the partitions of the drive you're booted from. You'll need to boot from a backup or a Lion install disk before you can resize your system's main drive.

Comment: On the contrary, i do it all the time, as long as u have space at the end of a partition.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I've been wasting time booting from a startup disk. Seeing all the other options grayed out made me think resizing wasn't available. Thanks.